# Initializing Reference Class objects - `new(...)` vs. `getRefClass(...)$new()`

Tags: r, initialization, pass-by-reference

Are there drawbacks to using `new("SomeClass")` instead of `getRefClass("Someclass")$new()` for Reference Classes?

Comment: `?ReferenceClasses` says "'$new(...)' This method is equivalent to the function 'new' with the class name as an argument."

Comment: Okay, thanks. It was just pointed out to me a couple times that I should use `$new(...)` and I wondered why. Must have missed the relevant section in the help file.